# AppDelegate property being reset between viewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to share data between various viewControllers, I'm using a property declared in the appDelegate. I set the property in my first viewController and when I print out the contents, everything looks fine, but after I call a custom class method, the property gets set to some random value that seems to change every time I run the app. See code below:

appDelegate .h

```
NSDate *lastUpdated;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *lastUpdated;
```

viewController .m

```
AppDelegateClassName *appDelegate = (AppDelegateClassName *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate setLastUpdated:[NSDate date]];
```

After I set the property, I then call the following custom class method with a reference to the viewController as a parameter:

viewController .m

```
ForceData *forceData = [[ForceData alloc] init];
[forceData queryServiceWithParent:self];
```

If I try and display the contents of the appDelegate property within my custom class, it returns a random value. Once the custom class returns to the viewController, the appDelegate property stays as the random value.

I can't see what's going wrong. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

UPDATE

Here is the code within the queryServiceWithParent method:

```
- (void)queryServiceWithParent:(UIViewController *)controller {

    viewController = (ForcesTableViewController *)controller;
    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com"];
    theURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:url] retain];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}
```

I'm still having this problem so any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE:

I've spent some more time looking at this and I can display the contents of lastUpdated anywhere within the queryServiceWithParent (just above) and it displays fine. But if I display the same property in the connectionDidFinishLoading, it's reset. Very stuck with this one!

Comment: did you `synthesize` the property accessors for `lastUpdated`?

Comment: Can you show the code in queryServiceWithParent that uses this property?

Comment: @Anurag - yes I did syenthesize the property, forgot to add that bit in my code snippets.

Comment: @Firoze Lafeer - My net has been down past few days, but I've now added the code in queryServiceWithParent to my original question.

Comment: Do you know how to set a symbolic breakpoint? Set one on [AppDelegate setLastUpdated:] and see where else that is called from. Then post that code.

Comment: I've set the symbolic breakpoint for "[appDelegate setLastUpdated:] but it didn't return anything. When I tried just "setLastUpdated:" it returned the synthesize lastUpdated within the AppDelegate.m file...

Comment: Can you try to set the property to copy instead of retain and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this *sounds* to me is that your NSDate property is autoreleased at some point, even though your memory management sounds fine the way you describe it.

Can you try to add an extra retain to your NSDate, as in:

`appDelegate.lastUpdated = [[NSDate date] retain]`

If that helps than we need more information about your code to find out where your memory management has errors. i.e. the complete header and main file of your appDelegate and viewController.

Comment: Ah sorry, I managed to resolve this issue on another forum. However, you were right, the date was being released.